# JSON Multiple Array to show list

Tags: php, json

```
Array
(
    [0] => Job
    [1] => 
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [AppDataId] => 16368
                    [JobTitle] => Sigma Six Black Belt/Lean Administration Consultant
                    [Abstract] => Sigma Six Black Belt/Lean Administration Consultan ... - open
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [AppDataId] => 16367
                    [JobTitle] => General Manager (Power Generation)
                    [Abstract] => General Manager (Power Generation) - Botswana
                )

            [2] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [AppDataId] => 16366
                    [JobTitle] => Resident  Engineer - Mpumalanga
                    [Abstract] => Resident  Engineer - Mpumalanga - Mpumalanga
                )

        )

    [3] => 
)
```

I need to get this into a PHP array and list all the JobTitle's or any other field

I've done this but I cannot figure out how to access only JobTitle firstly, and then secondly list all of them. $json_url is the actual url of the json file that outputs the info above.

```
$json1 = file_get_contents($json_url);
$array = json_decode($json1);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($array);
echo "</pre>";

$strJob=array();
foreach ($array as $value) { 
    $strJob[2][1]=$value->JobTitle;
}
echo '<br/>';
print_r($strJob);
echo '<br/>';
```

Comment: `$strJob[2][1]=$value->JobTitle;` - now how is that supposed to make any sense? The only entry you are creating in your array `$strJob` is the one under the keys [2][1], and you are overwriting that one in every loop iteration.

Comment: You want to loop over `$array[2]` to begin with, because only that contains the sub-structure of objects to loop over. And then you simply add the job title as a _new_ entry into your array, `$strJob[]=$value->JobTitle;`

Comment: How would I loop over only $array[2] ?

Comment: Same way as you are trying to loop over $array right now …?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use below syntax:

```
if(isset($array[2])) {
  foreach ($array[2] as $value) {
     echo 'JobTitle ->' . $value->JobTitle . '<br/>';
     echo 'AppDataId ->' . $value->AppDataId. '<br/>';
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that is what I was looking for.